# Significato dell'espressione "altro che balle"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Gli occhiali d'oro*, di Giorgio Bassani, ho letto:

> Spiegò quindi calmo, indifferente, ma non senza una punta di orgoglio, che soffriva da circa un mese delle conseguenze di un «regalo delle verginelle di via Bomporto»: una «notevole  fregatura, **altro che balle**!», a causa della quale aveva dovuto sospendere «anche» la ginnastica in palestra.

So che "balla" in senso figurato può significare una bugia, una frottola, ma non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "altro che balle" che appare nel passaggio precedente. Una ricerca su Google, però, mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza usata. Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Balla" si usa in effetti per indicare una bugia o una frottola. Nella frase in questione l'espressione è rafforzativa e indica che la "fregatura" di cui parla era una cosa seria e tutt'altro che una fandonia o comunque una cosa da sottovalutare.

Indica anche che la definizione della "fregatura" è da considerarsi definitiva ed è inutile ricamarci sopra. Un'espressione simile potrebbe essere **"punto e basta"**.

Comment: In aggiunta, ecco come Treccani definisce il significato e l'uso di «altro che»: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/altroche-o-altro-che_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Comment: Conosco l'espressione "punto e basta", ma ho sempre pensato che abbia un altro senso, come per dire "non ammetto discussioni su questo".

Comment: @charo è corretto... volevo solo dire che (opinione personale) l'espressione "altro che balle" nella frase utilizzata potrebbe assumere anche questa sfumatura di significato.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con questa risposta: il parlante sta sottolineando in modo reciso la gravità del fatto che comunica. Si potrebbe dire anche “altro che storie!”, “mica no!” e, in modo più icastico (e forse più moderno) anche “mica cazzi!”

Comment: @DaG anche "Mica pizza e fichi" XD

Answer (score 3):

Penso qui sia importante definire l’espressione ***[altro che](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/altroche-o-altro-che_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) .***  Treccani confrontando le due locuzioni *altroché* e *altro che*  dice:

> La grafia separata ***altro che***, invece, si usa quando la locuzione indica esclusione o preferenza rispetto a un altro elemento
>
> - *Fatti, altro che chiacchiere*
> - *Altro che il luna park, altro che il cinema, altro che Internet (Jovanotti, Il più grande spettacolo dopo il big bang).*

USI

> La grafia altrocché, presente con una certa frequenza anche nelle scritture in rete, è da considerarsi errata e va dunque evitata.

Comment: In effetti, l’avevo segnalato nei commenti alla prima risposta.

Comment: @Benedetta  - non l’avevo notato. Comunque penso sia questa la risposta. OP dice di sapere cosa significa balla.